# Riggifying. How to make the arms and fingers bend with the armature?

Tags: rigging

I made up my model, added some bones to it, but I couldn't manage to make the arms and fingers bend properly. They bend like some spaghetti
[image]

Also the "Weight Paint" mode (I know it may seem wrong or completely not right)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, it's hard to guess what's your problem without the file, maybe share it? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I have sent it. Feel free to change it

Comment: Wait no let me change it

Comment: here  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=9p106vr4" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/9p106vr4/)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without the file.
here couple of points to consider:
Activate normalize in options

go through the vertex groups to verify that unrelated bones don't influence the given region. Ex. fingers on the upper arm.
If yes, then subtract it.

In case you didn't try watching - [enter link description here](https://youtu.be/AuunjITq2e0)
DanPro tutorials are brilliant and provide useful tips.

Remember also that the hand is a very complex mechanism, not only 3D, real hands are not intuitive organs, it's one of hardest parts of rigging.

Comment: Thank you and also if ya need I could provide the file

Answer (score 1):

Well, obviously you have to modify the weight painting a little. Simply selecting "automatic weights" is more than likely to give you unexpected results. I'd say subtract most of the weight paint and aim for the joints to be the most influenced (red). Keep tweaking until they stop having that weird bend to it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Your bones are desegmented, bring them back to 1 segment:

[image]

- Put your *Subdivision Surface* modifier under the *Armature modifier*. Enable the *Preserve Volume* option of your *Armature* modifier:

[image]

- Recalculate the normals of your mesh (select all in Edit mode and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> > *Recalculate Outside*:

[image]

- Add some edge loops around the joints (elbows) to have a smoother bend:

[image]

- Reparent With Automatic Weight:

[image]

Comment: sorry i actually couldnt manage to understand some of the things. Could you provide a more detailed message if that wont be too hard for you. Ill appreciate it, I swear

Comment: I've added some images and given some details, please tell me if it's ok

Comment: yeah thank you I know will try to figure it out